# How to make dynamic IDs at the Notify manager (Android)?

Tags: android, dynamic, notifications

I have a problem with an Android app I am making. I have two buttons and both cause a notification after pressing it, but here is where the problem comes in. Both have an **unchanging ID (1 and 2)**

```
manager.notify(1, notification);
```

This means that the notification1, always appears the first in the status bar. It makes no difference when you press notification2 first, it  is always notification1 and then notification2. Now i need to know how to make **dynamic ID**?

Can anyone tell me a solution how i can avoid the unchanging order?

Here the complete code:

```
 public void sendNotification(View view) {

    switch(view.getId()){

        case R.id.button1:
            Notification1();
            break;

        case R.id.button2:
            Notification2();
            break;

        }
     }

private void Notification1() {

   NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
   builder.setAutoCancel(true);
   builder.setContentTitle("BasicNotification");
   builder.setContentText("Test");
   builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon1);

   Notification notification = builder.build();
   NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) this.getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
   manager.notify(1, notification);

}

private void Notification2() {

   NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
   builder.setAutoCancel(true);
   builder.setContentTitle("BasicNotification");
   builder.setContentText("Test");
   builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon2);

   Notification notification = builder.build();
   NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) this.getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
   manager.notify(2, notification);

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`System.currentTimeInMillis()` is my preferred way of generating unique ids.

```
manager.notify(System.currentTimeInMillis(), notification);
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick anwser! but where do i have to but this? sorry but i am really noobie :(

Comment: THANKS MAN!!! omg you are the best :D
i asked for help in an german forum but it need days for an awnser and then it didnt worked and now i am in an english forum and i get a short and competent awnser after 2min :D thanks again you saved me from hours of googleing ^^

Comment: Notice that while this probably works, the generated values might be unexpected. `System.currentTimeMillis()` return a `long` value that's bigger than `Integer.MAX_VALUE`, so the downcast needs to wrap the value to fit into an integer.

Answer (score 0):

```
//generating unique ID
int uniqueID = (int) System.currentTimeMillis();
```

Now you can use that in your code like this

```
manager.notify(uniqueID , notification);
```